# How to create an empty file using apache user in django or python instead of actual user of server

Tags: python, django, linux, apache

I need to create an empty file when createEmptyFile() is triggered in UI.
But it is giving error "touch: cannot touch 'hello.txt': Permission denied"
because instead of creating file with actual user (actualuser), it is creating with apache user

This is a django app using apache server, and using 'os' module and with 'touch' command i need to create file

```
def createEmptyFile():
    print getpass.getuser()
    os.system('touch hello.txt')
```

I expect file to be created but it is giving "touch: cannot touch 'hello.txt': Permission denied" because of file is creating using another user(apache) instead of actual user(anotheruser)

```
Output:
   apache
   touch: cannot touch 'hello.txt': Permission denied
```

Comment: You should define a directory with access rights for the `apache` user, and create the file in that directory.

Comment: Or you can configure your server to run the command with another user.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem can you elaborate please

Comment: With `os.system('touch hello.txt')` you're trying to create a file inside your django source code directory (the directory where `manage.py` is located). Correctly, apache does not have permission to write there. Create a directory somewhere else with the correct user permissions and then create your hello.txt in that directory.

Comment: @dirkgroten You mean i should use 777 permission for that created directory and user as apache of that directory?

Comment: never 777, if you set apache as the owner of that directory or set a group to which user apache belongs to, more restrictive permissions should work as well (660 for example).

Comment: What about to create a subfolder for each user, owner user, group owner apache group, and use `os.system('touch {here_the_current_username}/hello.txt')`.

Comment: the users in your django app have nothing to do with the users on your unix machine. of course, you can name the directory after the django user, but permissions and ownership should be the unix user that is used to run your server so that it can read and write to these directories.

Comment: hi @dirkgroten, how do you know `the users in your django app have nothing to do with the users on your unix machine. ` ? Maybe he is using a single sign on with ldap, or something like this.

Comment: @daniherrera you are right, but I doubt it :-)

Comment: @daniherrera, i'm creating text file in my app path only i've checked that too /my-danjo-path/hello.txt, still it is giving permission denied

Comment: I've created one dir with these config {drw-rw---- 2 apache  apache     6 Jul 23 04:47 properties} is that fine? but still i cannot able to create that txt file in this properties direc

Comment: @dirkgroten me too :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @dirkgroten,

With your suggestion i've created a new folder called properties and given owner as linux user and group as apache and folder permission as 777 and that worked fine any how 777 not suggested but in my case there is no need of having security of that directory:

```
1) mkdir properties #created directory
2) sudo chown actualuser properties #change owner to linux user (actualuser)
3) sudo chown :apache properties #change group to apache
4) sudo chmod 777 properties #change folder permission as drwxrwxrwx

below is the result:
    drwxrwxrwx 2 actualuser apache   111 Jul 23 05:19 properties
```